# Script counting characters in a text box using Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, twitter, count, limit, character

I need to enforce character count limit in my application. I found some JavaScripts from web but they are not working, Here is my code. I would be very thankful if someone can kindly see the code & correct whats causing problem.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ 
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() 
{ $("#update").keyup(function()
{ 
var box=$(this).val(); 
var main = box.length *100; 
var value= (main / 140); 
var count= 140 - box.length; 
if(box.length <= 140) 
{ 
$('#count').html(count); 
}
else 
{ 
alert('Character Limit Exceeded!'); 
return false; 
} 
});}); 
</script> 
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<textarea id="update" rows="10" cols="3"></textarea>
<div align="left" id="character-count">
<div id="count">140</div> 
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You may want to have a chat with The Old Lady to find out about code indentation. It's a human custom.

Comment: Some people have a broken caps lock key; for others, it's the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space in between http://ajax.googleapis.com/  and ajax

Comment: thanX a Lot methodin, you fabulos people :-)

Comment: Wanna hit the checkbox next to my suggestion to accept it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not handle someone keeping a key pressed (*as it will not fire keyup events until you release the key*). It will also not handle pasting text with more chars than the allowed number..

Have a look at this plugin http://remysharp.com/2008/06/30/maxlength-plugin/ which handles most cases..

Answer (score 0):

Script of counting characters in a text box/textarea using Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = "175";
    function limiter() {
        var tex = document.myform.comment.value;
        var len = tex.length;

        if(len > count) {
            tex = tex.substring(0,count);
            document.myform.comment.value =tex;
            return false;
        }

        document.myform.limit.value = count-len;
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form name="myform" METHOD=POST>
        <textarea name=comment wrap=physical rows=3 cols=40 onkeyup=limiter()></textarea><br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("<input type=text name=limit size=4 readonly value="+count+">");
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```